# how to get value of dropdown into a mysql query in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I hope someone can help me with this question.
I am trying to get the value of dropdown menu and inject it into Mysql query.
Here is my code:

```
<form method=post onchange="putSomethingHere">
<select name="myvalue">
  <option value="7225">7225</option>
  <option value="7226">7226</option>
  <option value="7227">7227</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php
if($dbhandle){

  $q = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "
SELECT rfqlogs.id
     , customers.customer
     , contacts.Name
     , constructions.construction
     , grades.grade
     , rfqlogs.dueDate
     , rfqlogs.rcvDate
     , rfqlogs.proccess
     , rfqlogs.scope
     , status.status
     , rfqlogs.priority
  FROM rfqlogs
  JOIN contacts 
    ON rfqlogs.contid = contacts.cont_id
  JOIN grades 
    ON rfqlogs.gradeId = grades.grd_id
  JOIN customers 
    ON rfqlogs.custId = customers.cust_id
  JOIN constructions 
    ON rfqlogs.constId = constructions.id
  JOIN status 
    ON rfqlogs.status = status.id
 WHERE rfqlogs.id='myvalue' 
"); 
?>
```

Comment: Did you try `$_POST["myvalue"]`?

Comment: question couldn't be as clear as midnight and broader than the Golden Gate bridge.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I like when I change the drop down then query changes on-fly. let me check your idea too.

Comment: @triHeadLLC In that case you will want to use AJAX to call a separate PHP file you create. The approach would be the same in PHP though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate both the script that outputs the form and the script that handles the form submission. You could merge both in the same file but for a basic implementation, let's use separated files.

Let's call form.php the script that outputs the form (the whole HTML structure is not included).

```
<form method="post" onchange="putSomethingHere" action="handler.php">
  <select name="myvalue">
    <option value="7225">7225</option>
    <option value="7226">7226</option>
    <option value="7227">7227</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

The script that handles the form submission (i won't review your SQL, it's supposed to be functional):

```
<?php
  // $dbhandle definition goes here
  $myvalue = isset($_REQUEST['myvalue']) ? $_REQUEST['myvalue'] : false;
  // You can check whether `myvalue` was sent in the request or not, then take the required action.
  // validate and sanitize $myvalue here, use intval() if `myvalue` must always be an integer or mysqli_real_escape_string() in case it's an string.
  if($dbhandle){
    $q = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "SELECT rfqlogs.id, customers.customer, 
      contacts.Name, constructions.construction, grades.grade, 
      rfqlogs.dueDate, rfqlogs.rcvDate, rfqlogs.proccess,
      rfqlogs.scope, status.status, rfqlogs.priority
      FROM rfqlogs
      INNER JOIN contacts ON rfqlogs.contid = contacts.cont_id
      INNER JOIN grades ON rfqlogs.gradeId = grades.grd_id
      INNER JOIN customers ON rfqlogs.custId = customers.cust_id
      INNER JOIN constructions ON rfqlogs.constId = constructions.id
      INNER JOIN status ON rfqlogs.status = status.id
      WHERE rfqlogs.id='$myvalue'"); 
?>
```

PD: You can use both $_REQUEST and $_POST this case.

Comment: This code and query are working on another page.  What actually I want to do is, the drop down populate from the same query, but to make it short I just typed the values manually. My question might be stupid. I need to display the customers (INNER JOIN customers ON rfqlogs.custId = customers.cust_id) in a textbox. I assume even I don't need any extra codes, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) :

Try this :

```
<form method="post" onchange="putSomethingHere">
<select name="myvalue">
<option value="7225">7225</option>
<option value="7226">7226</option>
<option value="7227">7227</option>
</select>
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $myvalue= $_POST["myvalue"];
}
if($dbhandle){

$q = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "SELECT rfqlogs.id, customers.customer, 
contacts.Name,
constructions.construction, grades.grade, rfqlogs.dueDate, rfqlogs.rcvDate, 
rfqlogs.proccess,
rfqlogs.scope, status.status, rfqlogs.priority
FROM rfqlogs
INNER JOIN contacts ON rfqlogs.contid = contacts.cont_id
INNER JOIN grades ON rfqlogs.gradeId = grades.grd_id
INNER JOIN customers ON rfqlogs.custId = customers.cust_id
INNER JOIN constructions ON rfqlogs.constId = constructions.id
INNER JOIN status ON rfqlogs.status = status.id
WHERE rfqlogs.id='".$myvalue."' "); 
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean I don't need JavaScript?

Answer (score -2):

```
$_POST["myvalue"];
```

This should do the trick. The php $_POST global variable holds all variables that has been sent from your form.
So by replacing the array key, you can get any variable you want.

Comment: I am very new in PHP. How should I use the $_POST["myvalue"] in the query, should I add it directly?

Comment: you can use it directly in your query but the best way to use it is to initalize a new variable to hold its value then use it in your query. $myvalue = $_POST["myvalue"];